# JavaFX - Set default CSS stylesheet for the whole Application

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm pretty new to JavaFX, I'm trying to change my application aspect via CSS. First time it works fine, when I switch to another scene CSS' classes are not applied.
Because my project has 10 scenes, I prefer to use a single CSS file to apply my style to all scenes by using this statement:
`StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(this.getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());`
into `start()` method.
How can I apply to all scenes my CSS file globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the following two lines:

```
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_MODENA);
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toString());
```

The first line will set the default stylesheet to modena (here you could even choose to set JavaFX2 caspian as default stylesheet) using [`Application#setUserAgentStylesheet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#setUserAgentStylesheet-java.lang.String-), while the second line will add your stylesheet to the user agent stylesheet list.

It's not the nicest solution as `StlyeManager` is a private API (and will remain in JDK9 as it is now).

---

Other solution would be to subclass `Scene`, in which subclass you can add your stylesheet by default, then rather than instantiating `Scene`, you could create instances of your subclass.